# Sonar does not import lcov data

Tags: sonarqube

I am new to Sonar (using version 6.7.1) and trying to import test coverage report to Sonar. For this under C:\privat\3dp\coverage\lcov.info I got the data which reads like

```
TN:
SF:C:\privat\3dp\src\sum.js
FN:1,sum
FNF:1
FNH:1
FNDA:1,sum
DA:2,1
DA:4,1
LF:2
LH:2
BRF:0
BRH:0
end_of_record
```

In my sonar.properties I got a line for the import 
sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths=C:/privat/3dp/coverage/lcov.info

I tried that also with \ or \ instead of / but it doesn't work. I also have no error in any of the sonar logs or when executing the sonar scanner.
Also looked into similar issues here but none were helpful so far.

Comment: What version of SonarJS do you use? See the [documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/JavaScript+Coverage+Results+Import). The property names are changed between versions. Maybe the sample project provided can also help you.

Comment: I am using Sonar 6.7.1 and SonarJS 3.2 so according to https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/JavaScript+Coverage+Results+Import my config should be fine to my understanding

Comment: Have you tried making the path relative to project/analysis root?

Comment: I tried it with relative path. Assuming the base directory is the one from which I run the sonar runner. However same result.